# Why are my generated images not setting their position based on my mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to web development and I wanted to practice the HTML, CSS, and Javascript that I learned over the weekend. I am having trouble positioning my images correctly based on my mouse cursor. I can see that my images are being appended in the "inspect" section of google chrome but their positioning is not matching up with how the style indicates. Is there a problem with my HTML, CSS, or Javascript or all three? I want it to work similarly to http://howlooongcanthisgoon.com/
[1](https://jsfiddle.net/hf7b2t6z/)[[image: example]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phdJh.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Jaws that Bite My Claws That Catch</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #witchwood{
            background: url("witchwood.jpg");
            height: 100vh;
            background-position: 75% 20%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .shudder{
            position: absolute;
        }


    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="witchwood" onclick="wok(event)"></div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //document.getElementById('witchwood').addEventListener("click", wok);
        var z = 0;
        function wok(e){
            //finds position of mouse
            var x= e.clientX;
            var y= e.clientY;

            //creates the img element
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "shudderwock.png";
            img.class = "shudder";
            img.style.top = y + "px";
            img.style.left = x + "px";

            //appends the img into the div class="witchwood"
            document.getElementById('witchwood').appendChild(img);

        }

    </script>

</html>
```

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf7b2t6z/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.shudder` class is not being applied. The appropriate DOM property is called `className`. You don't set an `HTMLElement` attribute with `img.class`.

**Change**

```
img.class = "shudder";
```

**To**

```
img.className = "shudder";
```

Alternatively, you could use;

```
img.setAttribute('class', 'shudder');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem